# URI scheme (or other easy way) to launch RDP client on Windows?

Tags: windows, web, uri, remote-desktop

Is there an easy way (e.g., URI scheme) to launch RDP client on Windows? The following example only works on Mac, not Windows:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn690096.aspx

Anyone know why it does not work on Windows? Anyone know how to make it work on Windows?

Thank you!

Comment: I found this [tool](https://github.com/konradsikorski/RdpProtocolHandler) to create a handler in windows to launch rdp URIs.

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial solution to your problem.

Create this rdp.reg file and double click to import it.  It will make the system register the fact that it's a new clickable URI format and it will launch your RDP client as a result.  However, it will not pass any values such as username or IP address because when I tried this I was getting an error "Invalid connection file (rdp://192.168.x.x) specified" thus it's only a partial answer.

There will be other values of the same schema in the directory, say Skype.  So if you wanted to double check the validity of the code you could compare the below to what's in your registry already.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rdp]
@="URL:RDP Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rdp\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\mstsc.exe\"
```

Probably there is some flags you could add to the command to say IP here, Username here, and some kind of logic to say it's @ symbol separated in the URL schema, but it's probably just easier to map your href to a download of a .rdp file instead at this point.

To answer your other question Linux including Mac have included the extended range of URI schemas as standard, but Microsoft have not.